# Spring security : dynamic roles

Tags: spring, security, dynamic, struts, roles

I would like to do something like this in my jsp (using spring and struts):

```
<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ACCESS_<s:property value='%{#attr.currentQueue}'/>">
```

Sadly it doesn't seem to work since I can't see the content I should see right now. However, there is no error either.

Any idea whether it should work ? Is the method wrong ?

Comment: it's a duplicate presented in a different way... Will either remove one or associate them when someone answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using another Struts OGNL : ${currentQueue} instead of using a property tag. Which gives :

```
<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ACCESS_${currentQueue}">
```